# Flatten PDF stamp on Acrobat and Adobe Reader

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have a script that flattens a custom-made PDF stamp. It works well on Adobe Acrobat, but when I copy the stamp and try to use with Adobe Reader, the stamp does not flatten.

The dynamic part of the stamp works on both Acrobat and Reader, but not the flattening part.

Any insight into why this isn't working? I suspect the last four-lines of code need some tweaking but not sure how.

`````js
if ((event.source.forReal)&&(event.source.stampName =="#lacers-stamp3")) {
if(identity.name == ""){
this.getField("name").value = "By: "+identity.loginName;
} else {
var first = identity.name.split(" ");
this.getField("name").value = "By: "+first[0]+" ("+identity.loginName+")";
 
};
this.getField("date").value = "On: "+ util.printd("mm/dd/yy hh:MM tt", new Date());

if(app.alert(
"The received by and date fields have been populated already.\n Is this document ready for LACERS approval?\n\nIf yes, select 'Ok' and the PDF will register your login automatically. \nOtherwise, select 'Cancel' and the field will remain blank so that it can be 'signed' at a later time using the PDF signature tool.\n\nIf you have any questions, please reach out to ASO.",2,2,  "Ready to apply LACERS' approval?")!==4){
this.getField("name-date").value = "";
}
}
app.setTimeOut("",250);

if(event.source.forReal && event.source.stampName == "#lacers-stamp3"){
 global.docToFlatten = event.source.source;
 app.setTimeOut("global.docToFlatten.flattenPages()", 500)
};````
`````

Comment: I may be wrong, but Reader is not allowed to flatten items. In this case, there is nothing you can actually do about it.

Comment: @MaxWyss is correct. Adobe Reader can't modify PDf files in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments, now as an answer.

Reader is not allowed to flatten items. There is nothing you can do about that. The only workaround (besides using Acrobat) just so coming to my mind would be submitting the form data to an utility which does server-side filling and can flatten fields (individually).